# How can I get only a part of a json file instead of the entire thing with php?

Tags: php, json, file, api

I'm connecting to the trakt.tv api, I want to create a little app for myself that displays movies posters with ratings etc.

This is what I'm currently using to retrieve their .json file containing all the info I need.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.trakt.tv/movies/trending.json/2998fbac88fd207cc762b1cfad8e34e6');
$movies = json_decode($json, true);

$movies = array_slice($movies, 0, 20);

foreach($movies as $movie) {
    echo $movie['images']['fanart'];
}
```

Because the .json file is huge it is loading pretty slow. I only need a couple of attributes from the file, like title,rating and the poster link. Besides that I only need the first 20 or so. How can I make sure to load only a part of the .json file to load it faster?

Besides that I'm not experienced with php in combination with .json so if my code is garbage and you have suggestions I would love to hear them.

Comment: That would be a bit more involved. You'd need a JSON-stream-decoder, i.e. something that lets you decode JSON data as it's streaming in instead of requiring the whole thing at once. You'd then start downloading the JSON data, decoding it as you go along, stopping the process whenever you want. I don't know a specific library that would do this, though I'm sure they exist.

Comment: Also, the response is *quite* slow (takes roughly a second for me), so you might want to define "loading pretty slow". Maybe it's not your php code but the api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the API provides a `limit` parameter or similar, I don't think you can limit the query at your side. On a quick look it doesn't seem to provide this. It also doesn't look like it really returns that much data (under 100KB), so I guess it is just slow.

Given the slow API I'd cache the data you receive and only update it once per hour or so. You could save it to a file on your server using `file_put_contents` and record the time it was saved too. When you need to use the data, if the saved data is over an hour old, refresh it.

This quick sketch of an idea works:

```
function get_trending_movies() {
    if(! file_exists('trending-cache.php')) {
        return cache_trending_movies();
    }

    include('trending-cache.php');
    if(time() - $movies['retreived-timestamp'] > 60 * 60) { // 60*60 = 1 hour
        return cache_trending_movies();
    } else {
        unset($movies['retreived-timestamp']);
        return $movies;
    }
}

function cache_trending_movies() {
    $json = file_get_contents('http://api.trakt.tv/movies/trending.json/2998fbac88fd207cc762b1cfad8e34e6');
    $movies = json_decode($json, true);
    $movies = array_slice($movies, 0, 20);
    $movies_with_date = $movies;
    $movies_with_date['retreived-timestamp'] = time();
    file_put_contents('trending-cache.php', '<?php $movies = ' . var_export($movies_with_date, true) . ';');
    return $movies;
}

print_r(get_trending_movies());
```

Comment: Maybe even use [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/function.var-export.php) to cache the already parsed json. No need to parse it multiple times.

Comment: Even better: refresh the data using a background task, so the frontend will only ever access cached data and never have to wait.

Comment: A cron job was my initial thought but this is the basic idea. Given OP doesn't have a lot of experience with PHP I figured this would be a good starting point.

Comment: @ZougenMoriver Yes that's what I've meant. ;)

Comment: Thanks I haven't thought about caching it yet, seems like the best thing to do. Thanks for your helps guys, appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Sounds like a fun project!